Parametrizing the surface of a polygon
To introduce my question, I present some brief background details.
Curve Case
Consider three vertices $V_1,V_2,V_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and then consider the straight line from $V_1$ to $V_2$, given by
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\alpha)=(V_2-V_1)\,\alpha + V_1 \qquad \alpha \in [0,1]
\end{equation*}
and the straight line from $V_2$ to $V_3$, given by
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\alpha)=(V_3-V_2)\,\alpha + V_2 \qquad \alpha \in [0,1]
\end{equation*}
Then, the polygonal line composed by the union of these two lines can be parametrized as follows
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\alpha) = \begin{cases}
\frac{V_2-V_1}{L_1} L \alpha+V_1 & \text{if } \alpha \in \left[0, \frac{L_1}{L}\right) \\
\frac{V_3-V_2}{L_2} L \left(\alpha-\frac{L_1}{L}\right)+V_2 & \text{if } \alpha \in \left[\frac{L_1}{L}, 1\right] \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
where $L_i\triangleq \lVert V_{i+1}-V_i\rVert$ and $L\triangleq L_1+L_2$.
This parametrization has the nice property that it maps a point $\alpha$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ onto a point $\psi(\alpha)$ uniformly distributed over the polyogonal line.
Surface Case
Consider four vertices $V_1,V_2,V_3, V_4 \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and then consider the surface of the triangle $V_1, V_2, V_3$, given by
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)= [(V_2-V_1)+(V_3-V_2)\alpha_2]\sqrt{\alpha_1}+V_1\qquad \alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in [0,1]
\end{equation*}
and the surface of the triangle $V_2,V_3,V_4$, given by
\begin{equation*}
\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)= [(V_3-V_2)+(V_4-V_3)\alpha_2]\sqrt{\alpha_1}+V_2\qquad \alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in [0,1]
\end{equation*}
Question
Similarly to curve case, is it possible to find a parametrization $\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2):[0,1]^2\mapsto \mathbb{R}^2$ for the polygon composed by the union of the two previous triangles with the nice property that it maps a point $(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ uniformly distributed over $[0,1]^2$ onto a point uniformly distributed over the polygon surface?

I assume the triangles $\triangle V_1V_2V_3$ and  $\triangle V_2V_3V_4$ do not overlap.
Let $V_0$ be the midpoint of $V_2V_3$.
Then $\triangle V_1V_2V_0$ and $\triangle V_1V_3V_0$ have the same area, $A_1$.
Also, $\triangle V_2V_4V_0$ and $\triangle V_3V_4V_0$ have the same area, $A_2$.
Let $r = \frac{A_1}{A_1 + A_2}.$
Place point $P$ at $(r,r)$ within the square $[0,1]^2$ and construct the four segments that connect $P$ to the four vertices of the square, partitioning the square into four triangles.
The triangles $\triangle V_1V_2V_0$, $\triangle V_1V_3V_0$, $\triangle V_2V_4V_0$, and $\triangle V_3V_4V_0$ have areas that are respectively $A_1+A_2$ times the areas of corresponding triangles in this partition of the square.
Select the corresponding triangles so that their shared edges correspond to the shared edges of $\triangle V_1V_2V_0$, $\triangle V_1V_3V_0$, $\triangle V_2V_4V_0$, and $\triangle V_3V_4V_0$. Construct affine maps that map triangles to the corresponding triangles and edges to the corresponding edges.
Restrict the domain of each affine map to the appropriate part of the unit square, then take the union of these maps. Now you have a map from the unit square to your original two triangles that preserves proportions of area.

Can you explain why this statement "Now you have a map from the unit square to your original two triangles that preserves proportions of area" yields to the conclusion that $\psi(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$ ,$\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \sim \mathcal{U}([0,1])$ is uniformly distributed over the polygon?

You have a uniform distribution over the area of a polygon when the probability of choosing a point in any given region is simply proportional to the area of that region. Pick a region $R$ in the polygon, find its preimage in $[0,1]^2$; the area of the preimage is the probability of $R$ and is the ratio of the area of $R$ to the area of the polygon (which has probability $1$).
